# How can I view DOMString (from apache xerces library) in MS visual studio debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, apache, debugging, xerces

I am working on code (legacy code) which uses [Apache Xerces-C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) library.  I am trying to view the value of `DOMString` (and other related DOM objects) in Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger but in vain. I have tried the following

1) I Added the following in the `autoexp.dat` file:

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Xerces
DOMString=<fHandle->fDSData->fData,su>
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result: Same behavior, it shows the memory location

2) I tried to quick watch the `DOMString` variable using "`var,su`" syntax

```
Result: ""
```

I have asked this question at the [Apache Xerces General mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-general/).

In case someone encountered this problem and had a workaround, it would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the Xerces library code and it's usage in my code base (we included only headers), I figured out that there was a preprocessor directive (XML_DEBUG) for debugging.

You have to build your project (which is using Xerces project/libaray) by adding this preprocessor directive if not added already.

In visual studio right click on project -> properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor and then add XML_DEBUG in Preprocessor Definitions

Along with this you need to edit autoexp.dat file as mentioned in the post above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to use this with natvis?